# regexp - for catching all hrefs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to do this code

```
if($.trim($('#id_title_de').val())){
    $('a[href="#tab_id_title_de"]').css('background','green').css('color','yellow');
}
```

for 55 languages where the last part of `tab_id_title_de` - the `de` changes for each language..

I tried this with shorter way:

```
if($.trim($("[id^='id_title']").val())){
    $('a[href^="#tab_id_title"]').css('background','green').css('color','yellow');
}
```

but it affects even those whose `$.trim($('#id_title_xx').val())` is empty.

am I missing something?

Comment: What you're doing isn't regex, sorry to disappoint ;)

Comment: @Allendar got you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no regular expressions here, you're using the 'attribute starts with' selector.

That said, the issue you're getting is because the selector will select a group of elements, not a singular one as your original code did. Because of that, you need to loop over them. Try this:

```
$("[id^='id_title']").each(function() {
    var lang = this.id.split('_').pop();
    if ($.trim($(this).val())) {
        $('#tab_id_title_' + lang).css('background', 'green').css('color', 'yellow');
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aj988w0n/)

Comment: looks so nice, thank you Rory - working like a charm!